# ASP.NET how to set text on a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a master page called MasterPage.master which has a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>` tag. Something like this:

```
<fieldset id="NewTrade" runat="server">
    <legend runat="server" class="legend"><%= this.BodyTitle %></legend>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentMain" runat="server" />       
</fieldset>
```

The masterpage.master file inherits SiteMaster from SiteMaster.cs. SiteMaster has a public field called BodyTitle. I want to set the BodyTitle when a normal page loads but I'm not sure how to do that. Basically all I want to do is have a legend surrounding my master content and then set the legend text at page load time for each page. What's the best way to do that?

So, in say Default.aspx I want to do something like this in `Page_Load`:

`BodyTitle.Text = "Home"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(this.Master as SiteMaster).BodyTitle.Text = "Home";
```

This casts the Master page property of your Page to the base class SiteMaster.  You can also cast it directly to the MasterPage class (from your MasterPage.master), but if you are going to do this then @Greg's answer is better, although they will both work.  Just depends on your requirements.  Setting the MasterType property of the aspx page is a great solution, but if you are doing dynamic switching of your master page or would like to be more flexible, then the above solution would fit better.

Comment: I am unsure of what the BodyTitle property is or if it has a Text property, I am just using the OP's example.  My answer is just to illustrate how you can access the properties (in this case the custom property BodyTitle) of a master page from a content page.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `Master` property of the `Page` object, and cast it to your `SiteMaster` class.

```
((SiteMaster)this.Master).BodyTitle = "Home";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this at the top of your Content page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masterpage.master" %>
```

That will automatically cause the Master property of your page to be of the type of your master class, so you can then access the property without casting.

Answer (score 0):

Save the text in a variable.

```
public string Heading { get; set; }
```

Then add the value to this variable from the other page;

```
(this.Master as Site1).Heading = "Hello";
```